# A combinatoric problem

Tags: combinatorics

> The question is to find which of the following option is correct regarding $$\left(\frac{\ \ 2^{10}}{11}\right)^{11}$$
>
> $A)$ strictly larger than $\binom{10}{1}^2 \binom{10}{2}^2\binom{10}{3}^2\binom{10}{4}^2\binom{10}{5}$
>
> $B)$ strictly larger than $\binom{10}{1}^2 \binom{10}{2}^2\binom{10}{3}^2\binom{10}{4}^2$ but strictly smaller than $\binom{10}{1}^2 \binom{10}{2}^2\binom{10}{3}^2\binom{10}{4}^2 \binom{10}{5}$
>
> $C)$ less than or equal to $\binom{10}{1}^2 \binom{10}{2}^2\binom{10}{3}^2\binom{10}{4}^2$
>
> $D)$ equal to $\binom{10}{1}^2 \binom{10}{2}^2\binom{10}{3}^2\binom{10}{4}^2\binom{10}{5}$

---

---

This question came in I.S.I. B.Stat 2013 Entrance exam in which calculators were not allowed.I tried using some combaratorial argument but failed.Any help shall be highly appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this AM-GM? We have
$$\binom{10}1^2\binom{10}2^2\binom{10}3^2\binom{10}4^2\binom{10}5
=\prod_{k=0}^{10}\binom{10}k<\left(\frac1{11}\sum_{k=0}^{10}
\binom{10}k\right)^{11}=\left(\frac{2^{10}}{11}\right)^{11}.
$$

Comment: Wow!. BTW, a typo, k = 0 to 10 in the product.